# Can't log in after changing home directory

Tags: login, home-directory

I logged in as root in the console and ran this : `usermod -d /mirror florencia`

The folder `mirror` is located in `/mirror`

Answer (score 1):

Log in as root and change it back to what it was before, by running `usermod -d /home/florencia florencia`.

I don't know what you were trying to do exactly, but you should generally not change your home directory like that.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But what im tryng to do is share /mirror as a home directory in a cluster. 
Im newbie.

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE READ EVERYTHING BEFORE MAKING CHANGES!**

here is how you want to move a "/home" directory to another drive or location.

1. Logout. You have to be in the TTY only.
2. Open TTY by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1
3. Login using your name and password

now here is where we start doing things.

```
cd /
sudo mkdir mnt/
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
```

note: replace /dev/sdXX with the specific partition or folder destination. example: /dev/sdc1 or /home/backup

now we are going to copy the contents of things.

```
sudo rsync -aux /home /mnt
```

unmount the old partition or location

```
sudo umount /home
```

delete the old /home

```
rm -rf /home
```

get device UUID for fstab

```
sudo blkid
```

open fstab and edit

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
UUID=copieduuidnumber    /home    ext4    defaults    0   2
```

note: if you are using a different filesystem then change ext4 to whatever you are using. example: ext3 or ntfs

reboot and see if things are good

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything is done correctly and you loop on login page without accessing you might just need to copy your **.bashrc** to your new home dir